# How to insert a single field into a JSON using MongoTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

So, i am making this program, trying to learn more about Spring and MongoDb. I have built this ticked module, that uses a MongoDb to store ticket info in a JSON format. It looks something like this:

```
>  { 
>      "_id" : ObjectId("581fb1a24beb291d27f95a50"),      
>      "userID" : "581ddccb4beb29112a7b4f77", 
>      "ticketStatus" : "Processing", 
>      "ticketSolution" : "Not_Solved",
>      "ticketComment" : null; 
>   }
```

My question is how do i insert a comment into the "ticketComment" field? 
(I would need something that uses **Criteria.where("ticketID").is(ticketID)**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some messing around, i have found another approach to this problem.

```
@Override
public void addTicketComment(String ticketID, String ticketComment) {          
    Ticket ticket = mongoTemplate.findById(ticketID, Ticket.class);
    ticket.getTicketComments().add(ticketComment);
    mongoTemplate.save(ticket);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With simplest details use :-

```
Criteria.where("ticketID").is(ticketID));
Query query = new Query(criteria);
BasicDBObject newValues = new BasicDBObject(columnName,value);
BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", newValues);
Update update = new BasicUpdate(set);
mongoOperations.updateMulti(query, update, "collectionName")
```